# Raspberry Pi 4B Ubuntu 22.10 Bluetooth scan successful but fail to pair

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu, mouse, bluez

My mouse stopped working a few days ago and is unable to work since then.
I tried but fail to pair it again through either Terminal or Settings > Bluetooth. The Bluetooth right now is able to discover other blue devices but is just unable to pair any.

```
raspberry:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Device 6A:74:F0:20:DA:22 RSSI: -73
[CHG] Device 6A:74:F0:20:DA:22 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
[CHG] Device 6A:74:F0:20:DA:22 ManufacturerData Value:
  07 19 01 0f 20 02 f8 8f 01 00 06 7e fc 18 87 93  .... ......~....
  92 9e 4c e1 df 90 0b 56 4f cc 5e                 ..L....VO.^     
[DEL] Device 75:63:D5:1D:9A:CB 75-63-D5-1D-9A-CB
[CHG] Device 00:42:79:C3:CB:6D RSSI: -68
[CHG] Device 62:D6:F1:DD:28:60 RSSI: -74
[CHG] Device 62:D6:F1:DD:28:60 ManufacturerData Key: 0x004c
[CHG] Device 62:D6:F1:DD:28:60 ManufacturerData Value:
  0c 0e 00 3a 69 3c 20 8c d3 94 fb 1c b5 9e 7a e9  ...:i< .......z.
  10 06 3d 1d 6b 2e af 98                          ..=.k...        
[CHG] Device 00:42:79:C3:CB:6D RSSI: -68
[bluetooth]# show
Controller DC:A6:32:D9:2A:26 (public)
    Name: raspberry
    Alias: raspberry
    Class: 0x007c0000
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0541
    Discovering: yes
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x05 (5)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[NEW] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 RAPOO BleMouse
[bluetooth]# pair ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61
Attempting to pair with ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 Connected: yes
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service0008
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service0008/char0009
    00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Service Changed
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service0008/char0009/desc000b
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service000c
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Device Information
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service000c/char000d
    00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Manufacturer Name String
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service000c/char000f
    00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    PnP ID
[NEW] Primary Service (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service0011
    0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Service
[NEW] Characteristic (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service0011/char0012
    00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Level
[NEW] Descriptor (Handle 0x0000)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_ED_8E_0E_C0_BB_61/service0011/char0012/desc0014
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 UUIDs: 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 UUIDs: 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 UUIDs: 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 UUIDs: 0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 UUIDs: 00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 Modalias: usb:v1235pAA22d0001
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device ED:8E:0E:C0:BB:61 Connected: no
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled
```

Would anyone please help? I can see the JBL, and other bluetooth devices, just can't pair.

I tried to pair and connect with Blueman. Same result, my mouse can be found, but can't be paired and connected. The error message is:

```
Connection Failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownObject Method "Connect" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Device1" doesn't exist
```

Comment: The JGL  must be turned on first, then at least 2-3 minutes before RPi powered up. Then start connect 0

Comment: would you please tell me what actually i have to do? How to turn on JGL?

Comment: Sorry. It was misspelled error. JBL not JGL. Is  Wait a minute is JBL is Bluetooth mouse? If yes ........ connect to port USB 2 not NOT USB 3. You don't need to paired. It is plug and go. I had it on my 7 ports HUB. Otherwise check your battery.

Answer (score 0):

1. please check rfkill

`rfkill list`

2. If any of it is blocked, be it soft or hard, just unblock it.

`rfkill unblock all`

or
`rfkill unblock <device name>`

I would just unblock all simply.

3. Finally `bluetoothctl power on`.